# Setting a default variable value if param is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to assign a default value if url parameter is not set. Something like this:

```
try: 
    limit = self.request.get('limit')
except NameError:
    limit = 10
```

Of course that didn't work, that's why I'm asking. With this code, the default (10) is not being assigned.

Comment: What exactly is it that "doesn't work"? Do you can an error? limit is set to something unexpected?

Comment: What is `self.request`?  If it's a dictionary, the `.get()` method takes an optional second parameter that is returned if the key is missing.

Comment: Give some context -- what class is `self`? ie is the `request.get` part of some sort of API or did you write it?

Comment: @g.d.d.c ok I didn't know that. self.request.get('limit',10) worked, (this is in webapp2 request handler) but I think it should still raise and error if this second parameter is not set, no?

Comment: That's because your code is contingent on there being an error generated. It's better to just check the value (what's being returned) of limit.

Comment: The get method is returning None. Not having a value is not an error for this method. If you used the [] syntax to retrieve a value from a dictionary, then it will throw an exception if the field is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dictionary.get method help says:
  get(...)
    D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.

Then,
  the solution is:

```
try:
    limit_default_value = 10
    limit = int(self.request.get('limit', limit_default_value))
except ValueError: #catch a string that does not like decimal
    limit = limit_default_value
```

Comment: The request is not a dict but its get() method behaves similarly.  However note that if there *is* a value it will always return a string (e.g. '10') while if the default is used it will pass the default (e.g. 10) unchanged. This can be overcome by writing int(self.request.get('limit', 10)). Now if the form passes a string that does not look like a decimal integer that will raise ValueError; there are many ways to validate form input but you could just catch that exception and substitute the default in that case tood.

Comment: Rodrigo, it would be helpful to correct your answer according to Guido's comments.

Comment: Sure is nice having Guido around to straighten these things out!

Answer (score 2):

The other alternative is to do:

```
limit = self.request.get('limit') or 10
```

This works because the or operator will evaluate the left expression and return it if True, otherwise it will evaluate the right expression and return it if True or False. In this case we know that 10 is True, so if no parameter is passed, self.request.get('limit') == False so (False or 10) will return 10.